# Factory reset for MBA 2011

Tags: macos

I want to sell my MBA 2011 (13"). So, of course, I want to wipe the SSD to reset it to the factory settings.

The MB came pre-installed with Lion (but without restore media) and I purchased ML from the AppStore. Now, as far as I know, it is not allowed to pass on a copy of OSX that was bought off the AppStore (correct?). Also, if I try to re-install ML from the restore mode (CMD+R on boot), it asks for my apple id which I definetely do not want to enter here.

So, I seem to need to downgrade to Lion. I tried internet recovery (CMD+ALT+R on boot) but to no avail - it failed with a "-2002F" error.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually called Apple Support and they told me that it is not legal to sell an OSX version purchased in the app store.

The technically correct solution is indeed to (after backing up your data, unlinking the iTunes account and removing the mac from "find my mac" service) wipe the start volume ("Macintosh HD") and to do an internet recovery by pressing CMD+ALT+R on boot.

The error I encountered apparently was because of maintenance work on Apple's servers -- apparently sunday is not a good day to rely on them.

I was able to restore Lion on my MacBook without having to enter my apple id.

BTW: Internet recovery works, but is really slow, so be prepared for that.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best thing to do would be to create a Mountain Lion install disc, which is quite difficult, or factory reset it to Lion using the Recovery Mode and/or Disk Utility - and if you're generous put the ML Install App on the Desktop (By re-downloading it from the App Store on another Mac and transferring it to a USB Thumb Drive

Comment: This does work without having to enter the credentials (I did the USB drive method using Lion Disk Maker) but is not technically legal.

Comment: Check whether it is legal - some things may be against the law - or just against the Apple EULA - legally you are allowed to make a backup of your OS - and if it was pre installed to that machine it should be legal. You aren't selling it commercially so it should be fine